# Post data from inside ajax form to the outer asp.net MVC2 form (in a view)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-ajax

As froms can't be nested I need some help to resolve this situation.

I have a mvc view with 2 ajax.BeginForm sections.
Each section - the user select something from dropdownlist, or enters some data - and when he push the submit, some more data comes using ajax and displayed.

Now I want to submit the entire form - meaning - all those selection that were made inside the jave forms to be submitted with some more data entered on the parent view.

What is the best way to approach this problem ? how can I send data that is in the ajax forms to the main form post operation ?

Thanks,
Dani

Answer (score 0):

yuo can  submitt one form and at the beginning of the action get the value of the second form and do your transaction or you can put both in one form and in your action allow it to recive a nullable value what i mean is the value of the submitted control